# How to set file storage path prefix in vue.js?

Tags: laravel, image, vue.js, storage, vuejs3

I can use `file storage paths` inside `laravel` like so:

```
// $request->image = '/about/imageID.jpg'
Storage::disk('public')->put($request->imagePath, $imageData);
```

but when I try to display an image in an `img element` inside `vue.js`, I have to add the `/storage` prefix:

```
// response.imagePath = '/about/imageID.jpg'
<img :src="'/storage' + response.imagePath">
```

This makes using images from the `file storage` tedious because I can't use `imagePath` as `src` directly but have to add `/storage` prefix to every `img element`.

Is there a way to configure `vue` to always assume the `/storage` prefix, when loading images from the `file storage`?

Comment: "Is there a way to configure vue to always assume" - no, and it's a terrible practice to modify global behaviour for local purposes, it could affect other libs, e.g. icons from third-party libs. Use custom component, or custom directive, or custom global helper like `<img :src="imgPath(response.imagePath)">`

Comment: You can use webpack aliases or catch the images while build and replace URLs

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who has this problem please try

```
Storage::getDriver()->getAdapter()->setPathPrefix('/your/prefix/here');
```

or

```
Storage::disk('discName')->getDriver()->getAdapter()->setPathPrefix('/your/prefix/here');
```

before saving your file

Answer (score -1):

**do that to create shortcut to storage/app/public**

```
php artisan storage:link
```

**save image**

```
$file = $request->file('image')->store('images','public');
```

**to get url of image example**

```
<img :src="'/storage/' + response.imagePath">
```